# Determine the interval of convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\cos ^2(n \cdot x)+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So, hey.
I was sincerely trying to find it by myself with Weierstrass M-test, but failed occasionally, because I ended up with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$,which is a divergent series. Thus, I'm asking for your help.
What should I do in order to determine the interval of convergence of the given series? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(nx)+\sqrt{n}} \ge \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}$.

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, by direct comparison, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(nx)+\sqrt{n}}$  diverges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So the "interval" of convergence would be $\emptyset$ (the emptyset).

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(nx)+\sqrt n}\ge \frac1{\sqrt n+1}\sim\frac1{\sqrt n}$$
and the Riemann series $\sum \frac1{\sqrt n}$ is divergent so the given series is divergent for all $x$.